# Can not satisfy generic constraint with subclass?

Tags: swift, generics

I have following compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type ‘PostTagViewModel<CreatePostMediaViewModel>’ to expected argument type ‘PostTagViewModel<PostMediaViewModel>’
```

CreatePostMediaViewModel is subclass of PostMediaViewModel, so on the first glance it seemed like this should work out of the box, but sadly it does not?

EDIT:
Some addtional info, swift array is generic and I can pass [Subclass] where parameter is declared [Baseclass]

Comment: No. Swift generics are *invariant*.

Comment: @Sweeper not sure about that one, I can pass Array<Subclass> where parameter is declared Array<Baseclass>

Comment: I know, and that is an exception, not the rule. (And also not a particularly *good* exception in my opinion)